# Trying to make sense of the word "tacit". Please correct my analysis

Tags: meaning, usage, vocabulary

**Definition of tacit​**
Source: Merriam Webster Dictionary

> 1. Expressed or carried on without words or speech
>    *Example*: the blush was a tacit answer— Bram Stoker
> 2. Implied or indicated (as by an act or by silence) but not actually expressed
>    *Example*: tacit consent; tacit admission of guilt

It seems to me that both meanings of this word carry a connotation of being silent or not being expressed. However, the first sense implies that something is *being done* or *carried out* simply without words – that a task or endeavor is being done quietly. Whereas the second sense implies that someone or something is *expressing a message*, *meaning*, or *intent* through the use of "leaving breadcrumbs" for the audience. In this 2nd meaning, the subject is expressing a message without directly stating the intent of the message via words – it is the job of the audience or close personal contacts to take the clues and piece together the message.

Is my analysis incorrect?

Comment: I think your understanding is pretty correct. _Tacit_ literally means _silent_. Maybe a 'tacit admission of guilt' could be unintentional in some cases as well as deliberate in others.

Comment: Tacit can have either meaning. It can be by commission, blushing, eye rolling, shrug or similar non verbal action or it can be by omission, not answering a question ("taking the 5th"), not speaking up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your understanding of the second definition is quite correct.

The two definitions are:

- Definition 1 says tacit is something **expressed** but expressed without words. The blush is a non-verbal expression.
- Definition 2 says tacit is something **not expressed**, either verbally or non-verbally, but instead *implied or indicated*.

Definition 1 occurs when I call the cookie-stealing children into the kitchen to inspect their hands for chocolate and Little Timmy looks down at his feet and will not make eye contact.  Timmy's expression of not making eye contact is his tacit admission of guilt.

Definition 2 occurs when I call the cookie-stealing children into the kitchen to inspect their hands for chocolate and Little Timmy stays in the living room watching cartoons. I can imply that Little Timmy's absence is his tacit admission of guilt.

Answer (score 0):

The first meaning of "tacit" is silent, and therefore done without using words.

In the second sense, it is a collection of idioms: "tacit approval", "tacit consent", and "tacit admission".  In this sense, it again means "by actions, not words" - or also "by omission", by not saying something when you could.

So, for example, a mother asks her children "who stole a chocolate bar from the cupboard".  One of the children goes silently upstairs and gets the chocolate bar wrapper.  That child is making a "tacit admission of guilt".

Alternatively in a school, a teacher suggests having a test next week.  Nobody complains so they have "tacitly agreed to have the test".

Finally in a business, the head of marketing wants to change the logo from green to red.  He emails the directors.  None of them reply to him, so he assumes that he has their tacit approval for the change.

So I think this generally matches your understanding of the word.